# How to prevent write access to a Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a table in oracle, that should store all application properties in key, value columns. This table is a constant table(meaning no data to be written while the application is alive) So how do we prevent write access to this table for all DB users except Data base admin.

Answer (score 5):

Reading the fine manual: [Placing a Table in Read-Only Mode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables006.htm#CJAGAFHJ).

> You can place a table in read-only mode with the ALTER TABLE...READ ONLY statement, and return it to read/write mode with the ALTER TABLE...READ WRITE statement. An example of a table for which read-only mode makes sense is a configuration table. If your application contains configuration tables that are not modified after installation and that must not be modified by users, your application installation scripts can place these tables in read-only mode.